# 2 batch codes simultaneously word together

Tags: batch-file, path, filenames

I got the following codes:

```
dir C:\Web.config /b /s > c:\test2\output.txt 
for /F  "tokens=*" %%a in (c:\test2\output.txt) DO copy "%%a" C:\test
```

and

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

set "src=C:\"
set "dst=C:\test2"
set "search=Web.config"

for /r "%src%" %%F in (*%search%*) do (
set "full=%%~fF"
set "name=%%~nxF"
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "path=!full::=-!"
SET "path=!path:\=_!"
copy "!full!" "%dst%\!name:%search%= Web.config  - Path !-!path! "
endlocal
)

pause
```

my problem is with the second code that copy's files to an other location with filename=path/date/time the number of characters is to long for some of the files i want to copy.

what i want to do now is with the first code is put the path location in a textfile with before the path numbers 1 till endless. and the same numbers on the files i copied that where the path is from. so i can see it in the textfile.

i hope i was clear and hope you guys can help.

if i wasn't clear, i've been thinking and i would like something like:

Copied FILES:
filename is name1
filename is name2
filename is name3
.....

In Textfile:
Path of the old location and behind or before
 that the same name or number the copied file has.

Answer (score 0):

@Kale youve used `set path=` while I'm not sure how it reacts inside the enabledelayedexpansion...you should not use the word `path` as a variable name as it is already a system variable.

Ie, open a dos box and run `echo %path%` and you will see what I mean.

Try swapping the use of `path` in your batch to maybe something like `loc` for location .